# ANTLR 3 - Can I use it in other way around?

Tags: antlr3

I have in my hands a Java project that has a parser for some language.
And it works very nice to read and parse.
But I would like to know if using ANTLR I can also get the other way around, like given a the Java Object go to the string representation of this same object in the language that the parser was built for?

So if I had a CSV parser, I would like to go from the java Object to a CSV file(or string that represents the file).

Not sure if ANTLR is the way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How can any tool know what the CSV representation of a given object is? Not even the CSV parser knows this. It can only take a CSV input and see if that matches any predefined rule.

ANTLR certainly is not a tool for that. It is a parser generator that takes a grammar of a language and creates recognition classes (a lexer and a parser at the bare minimum) out of it. That's it and ANTLR very good at it.